# Strange behaviour of locale.setlocale in Python3

Tags: python, locale, lxml

I have the same beginning in two Python programs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml         import etree, html
from lxml.builder import E
import re
import sys
import locale
#locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF-8')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

In one case, everything works correctly, and in the other, I have uncomment the first and comment the second call to setlocale to avoid the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./html2epub.py", line 11, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 594, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

And, of course, nothing works when LC_ALL is not ''